# Sintaxe Pl do Postgres (syntax error at or near "integer")

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Estou com dificuldade em fazer uma Pl no Postgres, não sei onde estou errando, podem me ajudar pf...

**AS TENATIVAS:**

```
do $$
declare

    id_cir integer;

begin

    -- ERROR: syntax error at or near "integer"
    (SELECT ES.ID FROM demo.public.corp_especialidade_saude ES WHERE ES.NOME LIKE '%CIRURGIA%') into id_cir;

    -- ERROR: syntax error at or near "integer"
    SELECT ES.ID into id_cir FROM demo.public.corp_especialidade_saude ES WHERE ES.NOME LIKE '%CIRURGIA%';

    -- ERROR: syntax error at or near "integer"
    id_cir := (SELECT ES.ID FROM demo.public.corp_especialidade_saude ES WHERE ES.NOME LIKE '%CIRURGIA%');

    INSERT INTO demo.public.corp_sub_especialidade_saude (ID, ID_ESPECIALIDADE_SAUDE, NOME)
    VALUES (
            (SELECT SUM(S.ID+1) FROM demo.public.corp_sub_especialidade_saude S WHERE S.ID = (select max(ID) from demo.public.corp_sub_especialidade_saude)),
            id_cir, 
            'CIRURGIA TESTE'
            );

END $$;
```

**RESOLVIDO:**

```
do $$
    declare
        id_cir integer;
    begin
        SELECT ES.ID into id_cir FROM demo.public.corp_especialidade_saude ES WHERE ES.NOME LIKE '%CIRURGIA%';
        INSERT INTO demo.public.corp_sub_especialidade_saude (ID, ID_ESPECIALIDADE_SAUDE, NOME)
        VALUES (
                   (SELECT SUM(S.ID+1) FROM demo.public.corp_sub_especialidade_saude S WHERE S.ID = (select max(ID) from demo.public.corp_sub_especialidade_saude)),
                   id_cir,
                   'CIRURGIA TESTE'
               );
    END $$;
```

A IDEA não estava executando a linha DO só do DECLARE para baixo, por uma falta de atenção minha!

Comment: Seu código efetivamente possui estes 3 SELECTs? O que você pretende com `SUM(S.ID+1)`?

Comment: Não entendi nada de sua tentativa de explicação.